# Automate Data Validation from source and destination using ADF

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a backup server from which data is coming and that data is transformed and loaded into snowflake(DB) using the Azure data factory. So here I need to validate the data between the backup server and snowflake whether the data is moving to snowflake same or not. The data which is moved to snowflake may be more or less. Manually we can check but. I need to do automate data validation and find fewer data automatically by giving any parameters. Are there any approaches using ADF?

Answer (score 0):

I was first perplexed by its name, believing it would assist me in validating my incoming source data files against the required data types of the columns inside those files. The objective of the Validation activity job, on the other hand, is to offer greater control over the execution of your ADF pipeline; it acts as a traffic control for your ADF sequence of activities.

You can create a validation pipeline in ADF which is going to count of rows and source and sink and validate using IF activity.

**Alternative**

Write your own code using Azure functions to see data between source and sink.